# Pause the mayhem in Super Crate Box

Tags: pc, super-crate-box

Is there any way to pause the PC version of this game? There does not appear to be any kind of pause button built in, as even <kbd>ESC</kbd> closes the whole program.

Any others ways to put the mayhem on hold for a few seconds, of must a player be glued to the keyboard the entire time?

Comment: If your keyboard still has it, does Pause Break do the trick?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Nope. That was the first button I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>P</kbd> to pause the game, just tried it.

Comment: Wow. It's built into the game after all! There does seem to be something wrong with the PC version - the game will pause, but does not remain paused. **This is the correct answer** since a nice big "GAME PAUSED press p to continue" message flashes on screen for a brief moment before disappearing.

Comment: And, in retrospect, I feel like [I could have thought of that](https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/1042123-dirk-gently-s-holistic-detective-agency)